# Mouse goes out Screen too far on the right side (Ubuntu,Kde)

Tags: ubuntu, kde, mouse

Under Xfce I can put the mouse pointer to the right screen edge and still activate i.e. the lift of the maximized browser window. Under Kde the mouse pointer goes out farther and I have to move the mouse a bit to the left to catch elements of a maximized window. How can I change this?

Comment: If the monitor or screen is a CRT, then adjust the monitor's controls, (if it _has_ any).

Comment: no, its a tft. i thing its a feature, not a bug, for the mouse to be able to disappear..

Answer (score 4):

Me too had this problem. My mouse went out of screen to some imaginary location outside and had to return the same distance to come back to the viewable area.

**Solution**
Go to 
**All Settings > Displays**
If its as of my case, you will see a box call **Unknown Display** to the left of **Built in Display** in a big box with grey background

Click on **unknown display** and de-activate it by turning off the button just below the grey box.

This solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be your display driver. In recent versions of Ubuntu (14, 16), initiate "Additional Drivers" under System Tools -> Preferences. If you find alternative, usually proprietary, display drivers, you could try one of those.

I fixed the exact same problem on my Gateway NV57H by switching from the xorg Nouveau driver to the nVidia-375 driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by going to "Display" and finding that I have two screens. The main one is highlighted in red and there is a blue screen off to the side labelled "uknown". So i clicked on the "unknown" screen and there is a tick option to turn it off which i did. 
After doing so I had no more problems :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this issue of the mouse pointer getting out of the screen to the TOP is by making sure all displays on display settings reach the same height, and are aligned at the top.

I can achieve that all monitors have the same height by dragging the monitors with the mouse in display settings screen, to get them like this:

This is how you should set up your displays:
[image: This is how you should set up your displays]

Don't do it this way, since the mouse will go out of the screen since the top parts of the monitors are not aligned:

[image: Don't do it this way]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).